# Sound and Camera on HP Pavillion X2

Tags: hardware, sound

I've bought a HP Pavillion X2 Detachable laptop and naturally I installed elementary os.

However, there is no sound and no camera too.

I've tried reinstalling and changing pulseaudio and alsa, but with no effect.

I've noticed that my internal soundcard is not detected at all.
Can anybody help me with that? Should I download a driver for it? Should I install some libraries?

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching a little i found that this is a common bug and devs are working to fix : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1561278

I think you should try to [update alsa to latest version](http://www.stchman.com/alsa_update.html)

But i don't think will fix

Comment: :< 
So it seems I'm stuck with windows 10 :/ Sh...